# I cant call my method from class in form

Tags: c#, xml

Im new to c# and programming

i can make the method Work, but not when i try to call it from my class 'Admin', it think its just a minor problem, but im just stuck ... Again.. No overload for method "opretspejder" takes 0 arguments

any help help i would be glad

Here my class

```
 public class Admin   
    {
        public static void OpretSpejder(string Snavn_txt, string Senavn_txt, string Sa_txt, string Scpr_txt)
        {
            {
                if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Snavn_txt)))
                    if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Senavn_txt)))
                        if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Sa_txt)))
                            if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Scpr_txt)))
                            {
                                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                                doc.Load(@"Spejder.xml");

                                var nodeCount = 0;
                                using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(@"Spejder.xml"))
                                {
                                    while (reader.Read())
                                    {
                                        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element &&
                                            reader.Name == "Spejder")
                                        {
                                            nodeCount++;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                nodeCount++;

                                XmlElement Spejder = doc.CreateElement("Spejder");
                                Spejder.SetAttribute("ID", nodeCount.ToString());

                                XmlNode Navn = doc.CreateElement("Navn");
                                Navn.InnerText = Snavn_txt;
                                Spejder.AppendChild(Navn);

                                XmlNode Efternavn = doc.CreateElement("Efternavn");
                                Efternavn.InnerText = Senavn_txt;
                                Spejder.AppendChild(Efternavn);

                                XmlNode Alder = doc.CreateElement("Alder");
                                Alder.InnerText = Sa_txt;
                                Spejder.AppendChild(Alder);

                                XmlNode Cpr = doc.CreateElement("Cpr");
                                Cpr.InnerText = Scpr_txt;
                                Spejder.AppendChild(Cpr);

                                doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(Spejder);
                                doc.Save(@"Spejder.xml");

                                Snavn_txt = String.Empty;
                                Senavn_txt = String.Empty;
                                Sa_txt = String.Empty;
                                Scpr_txt = String.Empty;



                                // MessageBox.Show("Spejder Oprettet");

                            }


            }
```

and here is the buttonclick i want to execute my method:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Admin.OpretSpejder();

        }
```

Comment: Your method takes several parameters but you are not passing in a **single one**...why?

Comment: Pass some arguments when calling `Admin.OpretSpejder` like this: `Admin.OpretSpejder(String.Empty,String.Empty,String.Empty,String.Empty)`.

Comment: @RePierre then his method wouldn't do anything - it checks, in various places, for each of the parameters being empty.

Comment: @Arran, `String.Empty` is to exemplify the usage of a parameter and to make the code compile. I do not know what values should be there.

Comment: @RePierre, of course, but it's to save him then coming back with question 2, "why does my method not do anything when I pass in string.Empty" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared `OpretSpejder` method with *4 mandatory string arguments*
(Snavn_txt, Senavn_txt, Sa_txt, Scpr_txt):

```
public class Admin {
  public static void OpretSpejder(string Snavn_txt, string Senavn_txt, string Sa_txt, string Scpr_txt) {

...
```

So If you want to call this method you should either *provide these arguments*:

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string Snavn_txt = "..."; // <- Put your real values here 
    string Senavn_txt = "...";  
    string Sa_txt = "...";  
    string Scpr_txt = "..."; 

    Admin.OpretSpejder(Snavn_txt, Senavn_txt, Sa_txt, Scpr_txt);
  }
```

or as compiler suggested create an *overload version* of `OpretSpejder` with no arguments:

```
public class Admin {
  // New overloaded version
  public static void OpretSpejder() {
    ...
  } 

  // Old version
  public static void OpretSpejder(string Snavn_txt, string Senavn_txt, string Sa_txt, string Scpr_txt) {

...
```

Answer (score 2):

The declaration of your method says

```
   public static void OpretSpejder(string ..., string ...., string ...., string ....)
```

but you call it without passing any of the 4 strings required

```
     Admin.OpretSpejder();
```

Of course the compiler is not happy

It seems that the method `OpretSpejder` wants to create an XML file with 4 elements and these 4 elements are required because without them the whole block of code is skipped, so you have no alternative than passing the 4 strings required

If you are the author of `OpretSpejder` then I think that you should know what to pass at the calling point, otherwise you should ask the author of the code what are these four parameters

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Admin classAdmin = new Admin();

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        classAdmin.OpretSpejder("yourstring1","yourstring2","yourstring3","yourstring4");  //Admin.OpretSpejder();

    }

}
```